# matrix into vector of columns in matlab

Tags: matlab, loops, matrix, vector, multiplication

I have a problem on specific matrix multiplication.

- There is a matrix X(M x N) and vectors b(1 x 3), a(1 x 3).
- I need to multiply each column of X by b, so I would have N squared matrices (M x 3).(see example how it should look like below)
- Then I need to multiply each of this N matrixes on transposed vector a, which will turn my N matrixes into N vectors of length M.

Is there an elegant way to do this without loops?

My previous code which doesn't work properly:

```
[n,m] = size(x);
nn=3;
aa = [ 0.069 0.167 0.826];
bb = [ 0.132 0.302 0.917];
a = repmat(aa,[n 1]);
b = repmat(bb,[n 1]);
res  = ((-x'*b)*a');
```

I have one idea how to do this, but i don't know how to create one row (1 x N) vector from (M x N) matrix by putting all rows, from 1 to N, of the original matrix into values of the vector. 
example:

```
A =[1 2 3; 11 22 33; 111 222 333]   
A = [[1; 11; 111]; [2; 22; 222]; [3; 33; 333]]
```

I figured out that I even can not initialize such a structure. But if there is some way to do this, I still will need `.*` operation to work as common, for example:

```
A = [[1; 11; 111]; [2; 22; 222]]
A.*[1 3 3]
result: A = [[1 3 3; 11 33 33; 111 333 333]; [2 6 6; 22 66 66; 222 666 666]]
```

Comment: Could you restructure or rephrase your question so that it doesn't look confusing between so many variables being used here - `A`, `X`, `a`, `b`? Clearly state the input(s) and the expected output?

Comment: Your phrasing is very confusing, but I get the gist of what you want.  Give me a few moments to answer your question.

Comment: @Divakar - I used my mentalist skills and figured out what the OP wanted :)  I wouldn't mind if you took a look as well!

Comment: @greyxray - I've found a few bugs that I've fixed.  Please check my updated post.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allow me to rephrase what you are asking in order to suit future readers.

- (a) Step #2: This step is essentially computing the [outer product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product) between each column of `X` with `b`.  As such, for each column of `X`, where each column has `M` elements / rows, we will generate a `M x 3` matrix each time.  Operating over all columns will produce `N` `M x 3` matrices.  Specifically, given a column of `X` which is `M x 1` and `b` which is `1 x 3`, doing the outer product is a matrix multiplication between `X` and `b`, which thus gives us a `M x 3` matrix.  We repeat this `N` times, where `N` is the amount of columns in our matrix.
- (b) Step #3: Given your `N` matrices of size `M x 3`, you wish to multiply each matrix in this result by the transpose of `a`, and so the final output will be a column vector of length `M`, and we will thus have `N` of these.

---

## Step #2

To answer your question for Step #2: Yes it is possible without loops.  I would [`permute`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html) the matrix `X` such that we create a 3D matrix where the first lateral slice is the matrix `X` itself.  Think of a 3D volume, but the volume only has 1 slice, and this slice is the matrix `X`.  This slice is also rotated 90 degrees laterally and longitudinally.  If you further need clarification, think of a thin 3D matrix, where each column of `X` makes 1 slice in the 3D matrix.  Each 2D slice is composed of a single column of `X`.  The reason why I need to reshape the 2D matrix into this way is so that we can easily compute the outer products.  I do this through [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html).    The outer product can essentially be computed by replicating the column from `M` you're working on to the right and replicating the `b` vector to the bottom until we create 2 matrices of the same size.  Once you do this, you simply do a point-by-point multiplication.  `bsxfun` will essentially replicate the `b` vector into a 3D matrix where each slice contains that replicated `b` vector and it is repeated for as many slices as we have in the matrix.  For the 3D matrix of `X`, each slice will have its columns replicated to the right until we have a 3D matrix that is of a compatible size with the replicated `b` 3D matrix.

Therefore, Step #2 can elegantly be computed by:

```
out = bsxfun(@times, permute(X.', [2 3 1]), b);
```

`out` should contain a 3D matrix where each slice `i` stores the `M x 3` matrix of the resulting multiplication between column `i` of matrix `X` and `b`.

---

## Step #3

You now wish to take each of these matrices (which are stored in `out`) and compute the multiplication with the transpose of `a`.  Yes, you can do this without loops as well, but this will require a bit of manipulation.  Matrix multiplication (the true definition) is only defined for 2D matrices.  3D matrices do not have such a definition.  Therefore, what we will have to do is take all of our 2D slices in our 3D matrix and stack them so that they form a single 2D matrix.  This 2D matrix will have each `M x 3` matrix from `out` stacked on top of each other, so that the total dimension of this matrix will be `NM x 3`.  Once we do this, we can simply use this matrix and multiply this with the transpose of `a`.  This will generate a `NM x 1` vector.  This vector will have **all** of your `N` vectors of length `M` concatenated together into a single vector.  To finally extract out the `N` length vectors, simply `reshape` the vector so that you get a `N x M` matrix.  Now, this matrix will be stacked such that each **row** of the matrix contains one of the vectors you are seeking in the end.

Therefore:

```
[M,N] = size(X);
out2 = reshape(permute(out, [2 1 3]), [3 N*M]).';
out_vec = out2 * a.';
out_mat = reshape(out_vec, [M N]).';
```

Finally, `out_mat` will contain that matrix we talked about.  The first output vector is stored in `out_mat(1,:)`, the second output vector is stored in `out_mat(2,:)`, and so on and so forth.

---

Hope this helps, and good luck!

Comment: Here's the magic code to get that - `X.'*(a*b.')`. It's good your mentalist skills are being helpful here! But don't you wish OP would leave at least some feedback on how well a solution has worked out or how well the solution has went through solving it or just anything at all. I mean accepting answers do indicate that, but it's more like a robotic yes or no. But good on you, askers have you ! ;)

Comment: OP = other people?
I'm not a native speaker, so just asking.

As for the solution it fitted me very well, I just didn't knew if it's a proper place to say that the idea with **bsxfun** is brilliant) As for other people who might read this: look carefully on the links @rayryeng hided in his text, they are very useful.

Comment: @greyxray - OP means original poster, or the person who originally asked the question.  Sorry, StackOverflow lingo lol.  Thank you very much for your compliments regarding my solution BTW :)